# Who axiomatized classical mechanics in 1949?

Tags: reference-request, classical-mechanics

According to Peter Machamer's "A Brief Historical Introduction to the Philosophy of Science" (*The Blackwell Guide to the Philosophy of Science*, p. 7)

> ... classical mechanics was not axiomatized until 1949 ...

Machamer does not include a citation here, but nor does this fact seem to belong to "general knowledge".

Who first axiomatized classical mechanics (in 1949), and where can I read more about historical attempts to axiomatize classical mechanics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure who Machamer and Silberstein had in mind specifically, but, in any case, they are mistaken. Simon published [The axioms of Newtonian mechanics](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14786444708561148?journalCode=tphm18) in 1947, Hermes *Eine Axiomatisierung der allgemeine Mechanik* in 1938, and Hamel *Die Axiome der Mechanik* in 1927. Von Neumann even [axiomatized quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics#Postulates_of_quantum_mechanics) back in 1932. In a [follow-up note (1954)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/185955?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) Simon mentions an alternative axiomatization of Kinsey-Sugar-Suppes from 1953, but nothing from 1949. Kinsey-Sugar-Suppes cite Hamel, Hermes and Simon, but the only citation from 1949 is Hamel's monograph [*Theoretische Mechanik*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Theoretische_Mechanik.html?id=ie_OBgAAQBAJ). In a later [survey paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20114347), Suppes also mentions  Khinchin's Statistical Mechanics from 1949, but there is no axiomatization there. So perhaps Machamer and Silberstein refer to Hamel's book or misremembered 7 as 9.

See Tiemeyer's monograph [Axiome der Klassischen Mechanik](https://books.google.com/books?id=z3oYDQAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s) for a more comprehensive outlook.